# Path aliases in tsconfig.json don't work for all paths

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, webpack

I have setup path aliases in my `tsconfig.json` which looks like sop

```
"paths": {
    "@services/*": [ "./src/app/services/*" ],
    "@interfaces/*": [ "./src/app/interfaces/*" ],
    "@directives/*": [ "./src/app/directives/*" ],
    "@enums/*": [ "./src/app/enum/*" ],
    "@classes/*": [ "./src/app/class/*" ],
    "@components/*": [ "./src/app/main/components/*" ]
},
```

They are then imported like so

```
import { PageStateNames } from "@classes/PageStateNames";
import { UsersService } from "@services/users.service";
```

However, for some reason everything works except for `@enums` and `@classes`.  Can anyone help me figure out why? The paths are correct, in fact Visual Studio recognises the paths are correct but webpack (at-loader) cannot find the files. But it can recognise the paths for everything else

Comment: Did u get a solution to this? @Chris

Comment: @vini I didnt but couldn't tell you exactly what I did, I moved to WebPack 4 (only took a day in the end), updated TypeScript to latest version 3.9.6 which I think helped. I also turned off compilation for VS (bonus as it sped up compilation).